# Getting troubles with soql relationship in a custom object with a master-detail field

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I have the next SOQL:

```
    SELECT Ap_Mat__c,Ap_Pat__c,Email__c,Cuenta__c,Nombres__c, Scheme__c
 FROM Asociado__c LIMIT 100
```

Where Cuenta__c is a master-detail field and Cuenta__c is the master(Account). On my SOQL I want the Account's name but this return the ID. I try to change to:

```
 SELECT Ap_Mat__c,Ap_Pat__c,Email__c,(SELECT Account.Name FROM Account), Cuenta__c,Nombres__c, Scheme__c FROM Asociado__c LIMIT 100
```

And get this error: "idn't understand relationship 'Account' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names".
Or change to this:

```
 SELECT Ap_Mat__c,Ap_Pat__c,Email__c,Account.Name , Cuenta__c,Nombre_s__c, Scheme__c FROM Afiliado__c LIMIT 100
```

Also getting error: "Didn't understand relationship 'Account' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names."

I need the same for , Scheme__c field. it's also a master-detail field where , Scheme__c is the master in a custom objet.
Could you help me please. I do not quite understand how to structure the query

Comment: You want Cuenta__c.Name rather than (SELECT Account.Name FROM Account) if I understand the relationship correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't think so but it I worked, I switched only __c by __r in the master field name, so, my soql is:  `SELECT Ap_Mat__c,Ap_Pat__c,Email__c, Cuenta__r.Name , Nombre_s__c,  Scheme__r.Name FROM Asociado__c LIMIT 100`

Comment: Excellent. I'll update this into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to update your query to have Curenta__r.Name rather than (SELECT Account.Name FROM Account) as it appears you are querying a parent field rather than a child field.